# Jupyter notebook online and uninterrupted session

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to train a model in Jupyter notebook on my computer. Unfortunately, it will take about a few days (more than a week).

Is there a Jupyter notebook somewhere on the Internet that I could start, disconnect (turn off the laptop) and then come back after a few days and connect to the still ongoing session?

Comment: You could try out Paperspace Notebooks, disable auto-turn off while provisioning them. Similarly, most cloud providers like GCP, AWS have their own offerings of the same.

Comment: Quite a few things have changed on how it looks and that Python 2.7 isn't involved anymore (I think) but [this old guide](https://medium.com/@alexjsanchez/python-3-notebooks-on-aws-ec2-in-15-mostly-easy-steps-2ec5e662c6c6) provides a good basis for doing this on an Amazon EC2 instance. (Skip step #10; I don't recall ever needing anything like that.) It's more flexible and more direct control than the other offerings they now have that deliver you remote Jupyter. But that was from mostly before that. Plus there's now AMIs in the Marketplace already with Anaconda as an option.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is a server. You need to host your Jupyter Notebook session on a remote host. The idea is that your Jupyter Notebook needs to run continuously, and as a result you need a machine that runs continuously. The fix for your issue will be a server, now the problem that you will have is the fact that if you need specific hardware requirements, like graphic cards, a cloud service provider that offers servers with your specific setup will be harder to find than choosing to train your model on the cpu of a server. The main idea would be to browse Amazon services and a free trial of a service in order to train your model.

Remote GPU Machine learning training service Amazon: https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/train/?sagemaker-data-wrangler-whats-new.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&sagemaker-data-wrangler-whats-new.sort-order=desc

Jupyter Notebook on remote server config: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-run-connect-to-jupyter-notebook-on-remote-server